# Apache Solr in Docker Container

Tags: solr

I have setup Solr in Docker Container below is the Dockerfile

FROM ubuntu
 RUN apt update -y && apt install wget -y && apt install curl -y && apt install openjdk-11-jdk -y

RUN cd /opt && wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/8.3.1/solr-8.3.1.tgz && tar xzf solr-8.3.1.tgz solr-8.3.1/bin/install_solr_service.sh --strip-components=2     && bash ./install_solr_service.sh solr-8.3.1.tgz

COPY ssl /ssl
 COPY solr.in.sh /etc/default/solr.in.sh

USER solr

EXPOSE 8983
 WORKDIR /opt/solr

CMD ["bin/solr", "start", "-f"]

This is a basic  Solr 
container. Now I want it to run using SSL certificate.

How do I do it?
Not much help from the official Solr website

Comment: Hi, have you seen this page? https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_3/enabling-ssl.html

Comment: I have seen this guide. But nothing relevant to Solr Containers. Anyone using Solr Containers in Production please help